# Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for GooglePlus

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to use the `cordova-plugin-googleplus` plugin.

**I have read the other posts that say to add the plugin as a provider, and have tried to do that to no avail.**

When I try to visit my login page I get this error with stack trace:

> Runtime Error
>   Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for GooglePlus! Error: No provider for GooglePlus! at injectionError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1590:86) at noProviderError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1628:12) at ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:3129:19) at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:3168:25) at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKey (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:3100:25) at ReflectiveInjector*.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:2969:21) at AppModuleInjector.get (ng:///AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:332:145) at AppModuleInjector.getInternal (ng:///AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:615:44) at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:3936:44) at LoginPageModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:3937:52)

**Stacktrace**

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for GooglePlus!
Error: No provider for GooglePlus!
    at injectionError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1590:86)
    at noProviderError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1628:12)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:3129:19)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:3168:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:3100:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:2969:21)
    at AppModuleInjector.get (ng:///AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:332:145)
    at AppModuleInjector.getInternal (ng:///AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:615:44)
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:3936:44)
    at LoginPageModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:3937:52)
    at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13535)
    at Object.reject (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:12891)
    at NavControllerBase._fireError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:45902:16)
    at NavControllerBase._failed (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:45890:14)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:45945:59
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9283)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4508:37)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9223)
    at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4452)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14076
```

**Platform details**

- Ionic Framework: 3.6.1
- Ionic App Scripts: 2.1.4
- Angular Core: 4.1.3
- Angular Compiler CLI: 4.1.3
- Node: 6.11.2
- OS Platform: Windows 10
- Navigator Platform: Win32 User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
  Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
  Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36

**Login.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
//import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { User } from '../../providers/providers';
import { MainPage } from '../pages';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
  // The account fields for the login form.
  // If you're using the username field with or without email, make
  // sure to add it to the type
  account: { username: string, password: string } = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
  };

  // Our translated text strings
  private loginErrorString: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public user: User,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    public translateService: TranslateService,
//    private GooglePlus: GooglePlus
  ) {

    this.translateService.get('LOGIN_ERROR').subscribe((value) => {
      this.loginErrorString = value;
    })
  }

  // Attempt to login in through our User service
  doLogin() {
    this.user.login_basic(this.account).subscribe((resp) => {
      this.navCtrl.push(MainPage);
    }, (err) => {
      this.navCtrl.push(MainPage);
      // Unable to log in
      let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: this.loginErrorString,
        duration: 3000,
        position: 'top'
      });
      toast.present();
    });
  }

}
```

**login.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { LoginPage } from './login';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(LoginPage),
    TranslateModule.forChild()
  ],
  exports: [
    LoginPage
  ],
  providers: [
    GooglePlus,
  ],
})
export class LoginPageModule { }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the GooglePlus-provider to the AppModule (app.module.ts)

Comment: I had already tried this, but it kept throwing the error. I uninstalled all node_modules, and cleared my npm cache, then started a new project and did exactly what i did before and now it works.... GAAAAAH!

Answer (score 1):

Adding GooglePlus to `the App.module.ts` worked for me

```
@NgModule({

  ...

  providers: [
    
    GooglePlus,
    
    
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of the Angular, `GooglePlus` should be imported like this (app.module.ts):

```
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';

...

providers: [  
    GooglePlus,  
]
```